# Why do makeStyles and createStyles have to be separate (Material UI + TypeScript)?

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I've been using this construction that Material UI requires to deal with TypeScript issues a lot and it's really bugging me that every time I want to style a component I need to remember how to combine 2 different functions into something that will yield a hook (I could solve it with a snippet but that just never feels right to me):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    ...styles
  })
);
```

So I tried of course to make it more DRY by just abstracting it away into 1 function but I can't seem to understand how to make the types work for this. Here's my clumsy attempt:

```
const makeUseStyles = (styleFunc: (th: Theme) => CSSProperties | CreateCSSProperties<{}>) =>
  makeStyles((theme: Theme) => {
    const st = styleFunc(theme);
    return createStyles(st);
  });
```

This creates 2 problems: `createStyles` doesn't accept `st` as an argument:

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'PropsFunc<(value: JSSFontface, index: number, array: JSSFontface[]) => unknown, CreateCSSProperties<(value: JSSFontface, index: number, array: JSSFontface[]) => unknown>>'
```

And the function returned by `makeUseStyles` is suddenly expecting a required argument `props` of type `(value: JSSFontface, index: number, array: JSSFontface[]) => unknown`.

So I assume, since my attempt failed, that this is why there are 2 separate functions needed in the first place to appease TypeScript but it bothers me a lot that a compiler would dictate the abstractions (which it feels like it does all the time the moment I try to DRY out a bit my styling code). So my question is: why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use or upgrade to TypeScript version > 3.4 you don’t need to call createStyle. The [`const` assertions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4-rc/#const-assertions) that became available in this version can defeat type widening. According to [a code comment](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.2/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createStyles.js#L5), the function `createStyles` will be removed in MaterialUI v5 (though it hasn't been removed from v5.0.0-alpha.23 yet).

I am indeed not experiencing any type widening and this is also confirmed by [eps1lon](https://github.com/eps1lon) in a [github issue comment](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14930#issuecomment-473803262). The docs should definitely be updated.

Comment: I'm using TypeScript 4.1.2. It's not clear to me from your answer how that should solve the issue.

Comment: In short: there is no need to use createStyle anymore as type widening should™ not happen when you use makeStyle. Can you add an example where it does happen?

Comment: I’m really happy there is auto completion in the IDE because I tend to forget the final ‘s’ in these function names quite often. 

Comment: I see. Now I understand what you were trying to say and now that I tested it, indeed it seems that `createStyles` is not necessary. Shame that the bounty expired 